# How to call a function from another folder in julia

Tags: julia

I am new in Julia and saying good bye to MATLAB, The issue here is that I am trying to set a script with all my functions where I can go later and perform some operations.

I have tried to do so in a MATLAB style, I also tried to read the documentation, but neither help that much.

So the question here is: how do I set a .jl file in another folder so that I can call this file later on in Julia?.

Hint: I am using Atom as an editor

KR
Rubén

Answer (score 6):

You can include any `.jl` file in a Julia session:

```
include("/path/to/my/jl/file/functions.jl")
```

Afterwards, all the function definitions etc. in `functions.jl` are available.